# DevOps for United Kingdom region

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

I've returned to a project which is using the DevOps tools to track work items and commits. However, after signing into the Bluemix console I no longer have the jazz URL on my app dashboard.

It's is showing do I want to enable continuous delivery? If I click the enable button it always takes me to the US South region and looks to create a new work area. But I want to access the current work area which is in the UK region?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have a need to have the Continuous Delivery service in the EU-GB (United Kingdom) region, you can always submit that request through the feedback mechanism with business justification. Bluemix welcomes feedback. See: https://ibmcloud.ideas.aha.io/

Answer (score 1):

As stated in this [blog article](https://developer.ibm.com/devops-services/2017/04/18/upgrading-jazzhub-projects-bluemix-continuous-delivery-toolchains/), JazzHub has been replaced by the IBM Bluemix Continuous Delivery service. The JazzHub site has been removed and projects are now toolchains. The Continuous Delivery service is available in the US South region only, which is why you are being redirected.

You can find more information about the Continuous Delivery service at this URL: https://console.bluemix.net/devops/try-toolchains